# Npm is giving error for instance node:events:491 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js, node-modules

What is the solution of following error?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw5hR.png)

I already deleted node_modules and applied npm i . However, same error is showing again & again.

Comment: Please provide the error message text inside the post instead of using a screenshot. Additionally, you can close that process manually. Steps in answer

Answer (score 0):

Something is already using port `5000`. This can happen sometimes when switching projects and it doesn't properly shutdown. You need to close the process manually

First locate the `PID` number of the process:

`lsof -i :5000`

In this example, I found one `node` "Command" with a "PID" of 17592.

Now close that process:

`kill -9 17592`

You can verify that it's closed by re-running the `lsof` command in step 1.